# Hibernation of Windows on MacBook

Tags: windows, macos, hibernate

Windows hibernation behaviour is to close of all power need of your notebook and you don't consume your battery. But when you do this on windows in macbook, your device still consumes electricity (like notebook hardware behave in wait or sleep mode) and next day when you startup your macbook you see a bit decharged battery. How can we achieve the windows hibernation on macbook (with no electricty usage)?

Answer (score 0):

**After hibernation and closing affect, you should also re-open your device in original MacOS system (with "Alt" Mac key on startup) and also real "shutdown" operation**. This will cause your macbook to consume zero battery with hibernated windows. Thus, when you open your device and open WinOS, you'll relogin the hibernated with **ZERO CONSUMED BATTERY** Windows system again.